# How to show Display name in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, jsom

Hi I need to get display name like "John Lous" but this display the domain name like "USA\Lousjohn" I am using this code.

```
ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
currUser = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();
```

Is the above code correct. What I have to do to display the display name.

Comment: Kindly research in detailed manner before posting questions...

Comment: Yes Ankit, I have researched very detailed and then only asked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try following Code :

```
    function getCurrentLoggedUser(){
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        this.currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
        context.load(currentUser);          
        context.executeQueryAsync(getCurrentLoggedUserSuccess, getCurrentLoggedUserFailed);    
    }  
    function getCurrentLoggedUserSuccess(){
        var currentLoggedUserName = currentUser.get_title();
    }
    function getCurrentLoggedUserFailed(sender, args){
      //failure callback
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get user details

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.website = context.get_web();
this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
context.load(currentUser);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args)
{
console.log(currentUser.get_loginName());
console.log(currentUser.get_id());
console.log(currentUser.get_title());
console.log(currentUser.get_email());
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
{
alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace());
}
```